# Why on my code that checks for permutations, Characters also permute with themselves?

Tags: vb.net

So my code searches for permutations from a random given String, and checks some .txt dictionary files (which are loaded in arrays) to see the words that can be made with the random given letters. But my code also makes them permute with themselves. For instance if i put "ab" it should make these permutations "ab" and "ba". INstead it makes "aa", "ab", "ba" and "bb". Any ideas? (the given code is for words until length 3)

```
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars

                For i As Integer = 0 To Rank2.Length - 1
                    test = Rank2(i)

                    If InStr(Rank2(i), c0 & c1) Then
                        RankBox2.Items.Add(test)
                    End If
                Next

            Next

            Next

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 2 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars

                    For i As Integer = 0 To Rank3.Length - 1
                        test = Rank3(i)

                        If InStr(Rank3(i), c0 & c1 & c2) Then
                            RankBox3.Items.Add(test)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars

                        For i As Integer = 0 To Rank4.Length - 1
                            test = Rank4(i)

                            If InStr(Rank4(i), c0 & c1 & c2 & c3) Then
                                RankBox4.Items.Add(test)
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: because that is how it is coded? step through your code to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is exclude the arrangement of characters that repeat themselves, then you would need to add a check before processing the code inside the for loops.

For example..

```
            If TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then
                For Each c0 As Char In chars
                    For Each c1 As Char In chars
                        If c0 <> c1 Then
                            For i As Integer = 0 To Rank2.Length - 1
                                test = Rank2(i)

                                If InStr(Rank2(i), c0 & c1) Then
                                    RankBox2.Items.Add(test)
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            End If
```

Comment: that works fine thanks a lot, but the problem with this is if the random string contains more than 1 of the same character, it won't permute it. But thanks anyway huge help man :)

Answer (score 1):

Same solution as @RyanRoos, but with indexes. So the compare is with the indexes.

```
        Dim c0 As Char
        Dim c1 As Char
        If TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then
            For i = 0 to chars.Length - 1
                For j = 0 to chars.Length - 1
                    If i <> j Then
                        For k As Integer = 0 To Rank2.Length - 1
                            test = Rank2(k)

                            If InStr(Rank2(k), c0 & c1) Then
                                RankBox2.Items.Add(test)
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
```

So if you have `ab`, it will produce `ab` and `ba`

If you have `aba`, it will produce `aab`, `aba`, `baa` twice each, because the a at first pos has been permuted with a at third pos.